# Questions on ungoogled-chromium compile time

Tags: google-chrome, arch-linux, c++, compile, clang

I started the ungoogled-chromium install from the aur last night, went to bed, and woke up and it's still only about 3/4 of the way complete. I was expecting it to take awhile, but I did not think it would be this long!

I'm not sure, but think part of the problem is that I had a bunch of things loaded when it started which forced the compilation to start to use swap. After realizing this I closed everything, and now have 10G of free mem, but still have 2G of swap being used.

At this point, is there anything I can do to speed things up? Or any advice for future compiles?

Comment: It shouldn’t take 8+ hours to compile any software.  Something else is going on.

Comment: Seriously. Any ideas of things I could check? This is a very popular package from the aur and I was very surprised to see it still going. I'm very tempted to stop it, but I've been looking around and apparently it can take a very long time, but this just seems insane.

Comment: Swap is a high tide, the value shown won't go down until you reboot, because what's the point in flushing it?

Comment: @Tetsujin If the compilation was using swap and then memory becomes available, will it start to use it or is it now stuck using swap?

Comment: It will only use swap when it needs to. Just because it stopped using swap doesn't men the value will ever go down.